# Package additional war into ear

Tags: java, maven, war

I have generated an additional directory `/target/war` during the build of an ear file. I want to bundle the content of `/target/war` as `extra.war` and add it to the ear file.

How can I achieve that?

I inherited the project and it was previously done in Ant. The project used the `<war>` target and generated the file to `src/main/resources`. I want to avoid to generate any files into `src/`.

Comment: What you should do is to Build a multi module project. One module for the war and one for the ear. The war is a dependency of the ear

Comment: This is a special situation. The project unpacks an ear, unpacks the wars in the ears, manipulates the content, packages the wars and makes an ear from them. This is done to add features to a "commercial" ear.

Comment: Sounds like war overlaying

Comment: What is "war overlaying"?

Comment: Here's an article on [war overlaying](https://dzone.com/articles/mavens-war-overlay-what-are). This handles it in the context of Maven but it should be adaptable to Ant, just how is another topic, especially since almost every Ant build is unique. Note that even if war overlaying doesn't solve your problem it's hard to give advice on an unknown build  process.

Comment: I am not sure how this relates to my problem. We buy an external ear. Unfortunately, this ear comes without proper authentication features, therefore we break it up into pieces, add authentication, manipulate some files and put it back together.

Comment: As I wrote it's really hard to give advice on an unknown build. If you need to convert an Ant build to Maven you'll have to make a few changes to make it work properly (leaving the conventions of Maven sometimes makes things considerably harder) and one of those things would be to generate a multimodule project. Alternatively just use the Maven-Ant Plugin ;)

Comment: I am sorry, but my project is really special. The aim is not to restructure it but to solve the specific problem I gave in the question.

Comment: You may add the extra.war in same target directory and add it as a dependency to current project. You may check the Meta info files containing the entries for references and also add it under lib resources before generating ear.

Comment: Whoever marked this as "too broad" has probably not understood the question. I asked how to bundle the content of a directory as a war and put it into an ear. How could this be "too broad"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one way to do it (probably not the nicest one):

I use `maven-antrun-plugin` and do

```
<war warfile="target/${project.name}-${project.version}/extra.war" basedir="target/war"/>
```